# TypeError while uploading zip to photologue

Tags: django, photologue

I just installed photologue, and trying to upload zip file with images. Django (1.4) shows following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/photologue/galleryupload/add/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

There was error in MEDIA_ROOT definition: excess comma in the end of line:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SiteDir, "app/media"),
```